# How to fix "Unsupported AAD Identity" when create a call from webapp?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I call this from my web app, I'm getting an error code `9000 - "Unsupported AAD Identity"`.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/calls
```

request header:

```py
{
  "Content-type" => "application/json",
  "Authorization" => "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFBUDB3TGxxZExWVG9PcEE0a3d6U254TkY3UDFxM05tT0xEOHZJVXk0NmFtVWRaV1ZhbGdFUWx2Vkw4Mmp4cS1tZFpwOWdiY1kwdVB4U3ctOGlGd3JRM00zUWlBS29KS08zRzN3czNsNlFmZXlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoidTRPZk5GUEh3RUJvc0hqdHJhdU9iVjg0TG5ZIiwia2lkIjoidTRPZk5GUEh3RUJvc0hqdHJhdU9iVjg0TG5ZIn0.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.cQmQLHWUfs8iOOPHf5SmWJYgsjQqLjZq9W5pKZzwRBtiQoOsUHILZkGYKz7_jx0bW-p87Cq6mFzswnoK30smEH6l7VW-gkzrxc2JFuDh-nKvfemTKnI3O_ZjtrEJNp-sWZF5Enm28Mg5Lh4hfBrSiROO8b0gAMytLWx9Qjy3H5x_zzdy34D1B1O8nCFrx217olDzarDCd6KqPtfCqoS00mWqCIwlEvHSi7OCtBV0HaUEl07-hi9hovu-uaHTLRW50fFP9hfoWYOz5qRyidpGNRtR26rUtexlOXtceZKYv5fD_VFNiBdT7d06EiK58UBib08eHjcvNJ6NEhcW0xTOxA"
}
```

request body:

```
{
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/api/calls",
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
    "preFetchMedia": [
      {
        "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/beep.wav",
        "resourceId": "1D6DE2D4-CD51-4309-8DAA-70768651088E"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/cool.wav",
        "resourceId": "1D6DE2D4-CD51-4309-8DAA-70768651088F"
      }
    ]
  },
  "source": {
    "identity": {
      "application": {
        "id": "RealAppId"
      }
    },
    "languageId": "languageId-value",
    "region": "region-value"
  },
  "subject": "Test Call",
  "targets": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "RealTargetUserId",
          "tenantId": "RealTenantId",
          "displayName": "RealName"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "tenantId-value"
}
```

response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{
      "errorCode": "9000",
      "message": "Unsupported AAD Identity.",
      "instanceAnnotations": []
    }",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "RealRequestId",
      "date": "2019-07-23T00:25:12"
    }
  }
}
```

I n the request body, `RealTargetUserId` is an Azure ActiveDirectory UserID with an E1 license provisioned. `RealAppId` is the registered application id and with Permissions as follows:

```
Calls.AccessMedia.All
Calls.Initiate.All
Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All
```

Comment: Please include the full `Authorization` header in your question.

Comment: i do again and edit my post with full Authorization header and response date as 2019-07-23T00:25:12. waiting for your reply. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you need one of the following Application scopes to create a call: `Calls.JoinGroupCallsasGuest.All`, `Calls.JoinGroupCalls.All`, `Calls.Initiate.All`, `Calls.InitiateGroupCalls.All`.

The authentication token you're using, however, is using Delegated scopes. This tells me you're either using OAuth's Authentication Code or Implicit grant flows. Neither of these will work for this operation.

In order to use this endpoint, you'll need to request an *App-Only* token using the OAuth Client Credentials grant. There are instructions on how to do this in the documentation: [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta).

Also, you're over-requesting permission scopes. For example, there is no need to request `User.Read`, `User.Read.All`, *and* `User.ReadBasic.All`, you only need `User.Read.All` to accomplish the same thing. The same goes for `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As you mentioned, getting a token from the app before calling and calling with this token no longer causes the "Unsupported AAD Identity" error.

Comment: but i get an error as "Application is not registered in our store". would you help me to fix this error?

Comment: Hi @user35131 were you able to solve the issue "Application is not registered in our store"? Got the same issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix issues with "Application is not registered in our store" you need to make sure that you use a Bot Channel Registration instead of just a normal App Registration.

The Bot Channel Registration should also have Microsoft Teams as a registered channel and have calling enabled.

For more information see: https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/calls/register-calling-bot.html

The final step about adding the bot in teams can be skipped if you only care about API access.